# Replicate a table from one phpMyAdmin server to another

Tags: mysql

My boss is having me implement a system for our live site that copies a table from one of our databases to its own.  It's supposed to do this once a day; the database it's supposed to copy from updates every thirty minutes.  What I'm confused about is how to make this work.  I intend to use PHP for this and the initial suggestion was to use AJAX, but I'm not sure I see the point of the latter when the page we're using isn't going to be linked to by any of our other pages and it's not going to display anything.

How can I copy this table, much less get the two databases to communicate?

Comment: I agree with the answer on MySQL Replication- but just based on your question it seems like your boss wants something verify specific. Could you tell us WHY he would want a table to be replicated? There is likely a better solution.

Comment: this has nothing to do with  phpMyAdmin.  phpMyAdmin uis just another php script

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) no need for PHP or any programming only configuration.

Comment: Since this seems to be the dominant suggestion and I'm looking into the details of how it's done, I'm curious to know if it's secure.  We don't exactly want to leave our site vulnerable with any sort of opportunity for people to get all of our inventory information.

Comment: Well when using MySQL replication you are using only MySQL which reduce the risks related to using multiple technologies that can have their own vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to use AJAX for this, because AJAX is a client <-> server communication technology, and you need the data copied between 2 servers.

Depending on your database setup, you could do it in PHP, even though this would be more of a hack than a real solution. In PHP you could do something like this (treat it as pseudo code):

```
    $srcDb  = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'source_database_name');
    $destDb = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dest_database_name');


    $result = $srcDb->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE");

    $destDb->begin_transaction();
    $destDb->query('DELETE FROM TABLE');

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // format insert query from $row...
        $destDb->query("INSERT INTO TABLE (...) VALUES (...)");
    }

    $destDb->commit();
```

Depending on the size of the table, you will have a time when the table on DEST server will be empty or have incomplete rows. To avoid this, you might use mysql transactions, but with a large number of rows, committing such transaction would take a long time. This solution is generally very inefficient.

A proper way to do this would be to setup source server as MySQL master, and dest server as MySQL slave. This way the updates on the slave server would be almost instant.

Mysql replication docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

To only replicate one table instead of the whole database, take a look at `--replicate-do-table=name` option.

Comment: We only have about 1200 records in that specific table.  Its data is generated from another one that's updated periodically, and depending on whether or not we're continuing to stock some item or if we're adding a new one, records may be removed or added.  In the past few weeks, I've only seen drops.

Comment: With 1200 records you can wrap dropping/adding new records into a mysql transaction and you should be fine. Replication is still a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Is it possible to automate replication?  The idea is to copy the preexisting table once a day to keep the live site database current.

Comment: mysql replication is automatic by default. If you want to copy once a day using a php script, you can use crontab for this.